# How does Javas KeyManagerFactory.init work with multiple keys

Tags: java, keystore

I came across this Java snippet as part of creating an SSLContext. I am wondering about the `init` call, where a `keyPass` is specified. What if the KeyStore contains multiple certificates with different aliases and different passwords?

```
val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks")
keyStore.load(inputStream, "storePass")

val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509")
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyPass?)

val keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers

val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
sslContext.init(keyManagers, null, new SecureRandom)
```

How would you rewrite the code if `keyStore` contained cert1 (alias: one, pwd: foo) and cert2 (alias: two, pwd: bar)? Maybe I misunderstood a thing or two :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After double checking the documentation, and doing a bit of googling, it seems like maintaining multiple keystores and wrapping them in a bespoke composite keymanager could work, [as the author of this blog post is doing](http://codyaray.com/2013/04/java-ssl-with-multiple-keystores).

Comment: Not sure about that: According to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/KeyManagerFactory.html#init(java.security.KeyStore,%20char[])) : password - the password for recovering keys in the KeyStore

Comment: It's two different passwords.

Comment: i stand corrected, you are right, i got my methods crossed here. the Keystore#load method takes the store password, and the KMF#init takes the key password.

Comment: So having all the keys in the same keystore does not work? (if they have different passwords. In case with same passwords it of course works).